# What is wrong with this iteration method code с++?

Tags: c++

Given the problem to solve the equation by the method of iteration, but why the conclusion is wrong, what's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double f(double x) { 
    return 4*(1+sqrt(x))*log10(x)-1;
}

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    const double eps = 0.0001; 
    double x0=-2;
    double x1=3;  

   do {
        x0 = x1; 
        x1 = f(x0); 
   } while (abs(x1 - x0) > eps); 
    cout << x1 << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducible example with the expected and actual output

Comment: why do you bother to set x0 to -2 then immediately set it to 3 without doing anything with the -2?

Comment: The code work fine. It finds the correct value for x, where f(x)=x.

Comment: @Abel,And how to fix it?

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but did you intend to store a temporary value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    const double eps = 0.0001; 
    double x0=-2;
    double x1=3;  
    double oldx0;
   do {
        oldx0 = x0;
        x0 = x1; 
        x1 = f(oldx0); 
   } while (abs(x1 - x0) > eps); 
    cout << x1 << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```